# if $\cdot$ and $\odot$ are associative operations on $\mathbb{Z}$ when is the sum $(\cdot + \odot)$ associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, binary-operations, magma

Where $a(\cdot + \odot)b$ is defined as $(a\cdot b) + (a\odot b)$.

I know if $\cdot$ and $\odot$ distribute through addition (i.e. $a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b+ a\cdot c$) then the sum $(\cdot + \odot)$ is associative, but this isn't a necessary condition, since if we define $\cdot$ to be addition and $\odot$ to be multiplication the operation $a(\cdot + \odot)b=(a+b)+(ab)$ is associative but addition does not distrubt through addition (i.e. a+(b+c)$\neq$(a+b)+(a+c)) however multiplication does.

Is it possible that (a+b)+(ab) can be rewritten as the sum of operations which distribute over addition? IF so can distributing over addition be a necessary and sufficient condition for the sum of operations to be associative. If this is the case could someone calculate and explain, otherwise what is a neccisary condition(s) on $\cdot$ and condition(s) on $\odot$ which together make $\cdot + \odot$ associative?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, all associative operations $\odot$ on $\mathbb Z$ that distribute over addition on both sides are of the form $a \odot b = cab$ for some integer $c$. That's a pretty strong condition, and it's not surprising it's sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: @eyeballfrog . Thats an interesting observation, I wonder how one would go about proving it.

Comment: If $.$ distributes over addition on both sides, then $a.b = a.(1+1...+1) = (a.1)+(a.1)+...+(a.1) = (a.1)b = ((1+1+...+1).1)b = (1.1)ab$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks, so both operations distributing over addition imply they are both of the form $cab$ and hence the addition is also of the form $cab$, which is obviously associative.

Answer (score 1):

Use the associative properties you have of the three operations involved:
$$
\begin{array}{rclcr}
\alpha + ( \beta +\gamma ) &=& (\alpha +\beta)+\gamma  & \quad \mbox{ for all } \quad &\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{Z}
\\ \\
i \bullet ( j \bullet k ) &=& (i \bullet j)\bullet k  & \quad \mbox{ for all } \quad &i,j,j\in\mathbb{Z}
\\ \\
p \odot ( q \odot r ) &=& (p \odot q)\odot r  & \quad \mbox{ for all } \quad &p,q,r\in\mathbb{Z}
\\ 
\end{array}
$$

And now? What equality involving three integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ characterizes the operation $(\bullet + \odot ) $ as an associative operation? Write this equality. Then express both members of this equality and in terms of operations $\bullet$, $+$ and $\odot$.

Spoiler:

> $$ a (\bullet + \odot ) \Big( b (\bullet + \odot ) c \Big) = \Big(a (\bullet + \odot ) b \Big)(\bullet + \odot ) c   \quad \mbox{ for all } \quad a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z} $$

Comment: I am looking for equation(s) in terms of $\cdot$ and $+$ and an equation(s) in terms of $\odot$ and $+$ which together will classify associativity of $(\cdot + \odot)$. The equation you presented is in terms of $(\cdot + \odot)$ or when expanded in terms of $\cdot$, $\odot$, and $+$.

Comment: In spoiler, the equation is in terms of $(\bullet +\odot )$.